# Failed to add virtual machine resource. Linked environment pool is null

Tags: azure-devops, virtual-machine, environment

We have a new VM and want to add it to our Azure DevOps Environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops

When we execute the powershell script on the new VM to register it, we get the following error:
"Failed to add virtual machine resource. Linked environment pool is null."

more permissions: add user to production environment group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to add virtual machine resource. Linked environment pool is null.

The issue could be related to the permissions of the Environment.

You can try to grant the user **Administrator** Role in the following two security settings.

1.Navigate to **Pipelines -> Environments -> Target Environment -> Click three dots -> Security**.

[image]

2.You can find the environment pool id in the environment URL.

For example:

[image]

Then you can navigate to **Organization Settings -> Deployment Pools -> Find the pool based on the environment pool id -> Security**.

[image]

Then you can grant the Administrator role to the target user.

Finally, you can try to re-create the Agent Install script and check if it can work.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer! It triggered me, its indeed a security issue. A collegue of mine can do the registration. We will find out what role must be needed